# ServiceStack JSON deserialization - complex POCO - returning null in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-text

We are using ServiceStack.NET as our web services layer. Earlier to .NET Core 2.0 version of ServiceStack (v5.0.2), the below complex POCO was being deserialized correctly by JsonServiceClient (from C# of course). Now we are getting null.

From Browser/Ajax call, it is all working fine. Only the JsonServiceClient has the problem.

We tried ProtobufServiceClient, we are getting

> Nested or jagged lists and arrays are not supported

We understand that we may have to hack the classes a bit to get it to work for protobuf, but json was working fine pre-.NET Core 2.0.

Need help.

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class EbDataRow : List<object>
{
    internal RowColletion Rows { get; set; }

    internal EbDataRow() { }

    internal EbDataRow(int size) : base(size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            base.Add(null);
    }

    new public void Add(object o)
    {
        base.Add(o);
    }

    new public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index > -1)
            {
                if (base[index] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    if ((int)this.Rows.Table.Columns[index].Type == EbDbTypes.String)
                        return string.Empty;
                    else if ((int)this.Rows.Table.Columns[index].Type == EbDbTypes.Int32)
                        return 0;
                    else if ((int)this.Rows.Table.Columns[index].Type == EbDbTypes.Int64)
                        return 0;
                    else if ((int)this.Rows.Table.Columns[index].Type == EbDbTypes.Boolean)
                        return false;
                    else if ((int)this.Rows.Table.Columns[index].Type == EbDbTypes.Decimal)
                        return 0;
                    else if ((int)this.Rows.Table.Columns[index].Type == EbDbTypes.Date)
                        return DateTime.MinValue;
                }
                else
                    return base[index];
            }
            else
                return null;
            return (index > -1) ? (base[index]) : null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (index > -1)
                base[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public object this[string columnname]
    {
        get { return this[this.Rows.Table.Columns[columnname].ColumnIndex]; }
        set { this[this.Rows.Table.Columns[columnname].ColumnIndex] = value; }
    }
}

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class RowColletion : List<EbDataRow>
{
    public EbDataTable Table { get; private set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (EbDataRow dr in this)
            dr.Rows = this;
    }

    public RowColletion() { }

    public RowColletion(EbDataTable table)
    {
        this.Table = table;
    }

    new public void Add(EbDataRow dr)
    {
        dr.Rows = this;
        base.Add(dr);
    }

    public void Remove(int index)
    {
        base.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    new public void Remove(EbDataRow row)
    {
        base.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Data Tables aren't supported in ServiceStack Serializers and [DTOs should also not have implementation logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48880354/85785). I'd recommend decoupling the impl from the DTO you're trying to serialize and update your answer with an dep and impl-free DTO (e.g. with no DatatTable class references) which doesn't serialize properly in ASP.NET Core DTO as it's impossible to reproduce without a stand-alone repro.

Comment: Thanks @mythz. I get your point. But these are not C# DataTables but custom ones,not derived/inherited. Design-wise it is similar to DataTable, but a lot lighter and simpler. And these were getting deserialized properly pre-.NET Core 2.0.

Comment: As per my previous comment + link, these aren't DTOs which should not contain any impl logic. My recommendation is to first decouple the DTO you're trying to serialize from the impl that's populating them. The update your question with an populated DTO which fails to serialize in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as no-one will be able to repro the issue using the partial dependency-encumbered example provided.

Comment: @mythz. This got resolved. It was a mistake from our side. We somehow missed noticing a non-public constructor. Thanks a lot!